Where can I find Components_Pages_pagename_razor.g.cs?
So since yesterday I have been getting this error:
Severity    Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name '__builder' does not exist in the current context  BoltonBicycleKitchen    C:\Users\A S U S\BoltonBicycleKitchen\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.Compiler.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator  C:\Users\A S U S\BoltonBicycleKitchen\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.Compiler.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Components_Pages_RegisterCyclist_razor.g.cs  321 Active
I cannot find 'builder' or Components_Pages_RegisterCyclist_razor.g.cs when i search them up or follow that path on the error.
I tried deleting my RegisterCyclist.razor file and recreating it. The error still exists.
